# Uploading files to the server using HTML5

Tags: php, javascript, html

I would like to know how can I upload a file after selecting it using HTML5 in that way:

```
<input type="file" .... />
```

The line above gives you the option to SELECT a file, now I need to upload it to the server.
Since I don't know the answer I'll tag both php and Javascript.

Comment: A file `<input>` is not exactly new. Slap a `<form>` around it and submit it. (The form needs to be submitted via HTTP POST and must have `enctype="multipart/form-data"`.)

Comment: In HTML5, you don't have to close the `<input>` tag, so you can remove the final backslash. (This also goes for `<img>, <hr>, <br>` and the likes.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an upload script like this one :

```
<?php
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
  {
  echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
  }
else
  {
  echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
  echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
  echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
  echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
  }
?>
```

Check this link (http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp)

Answer (score 1):

[Here is the code of Upload file in PHP](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp)

**index.php**

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="upload_file.php" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

**upload_file.php**

```
<?php
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
  {
  echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
  }
else
  {
  echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
  echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
  echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
  echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
  }
?>
```